# Getting unexpected value while accessing value from Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a very simple JS program which is not giving expected output.

JSFiddle link: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bo3fjtv6/)

```
var p = {
        11735: [{
            d: 46.0,
            z: 06810
        }, {
            d: 30.6,
            z: 07047
        }, {
            d: 36.5,
            z: 07026
        }, {
            d: 36.9,
            z: 07032
        }, {
            d: 43.4,
            z: 07083
        }, {
            d: 32.9,
            z: 07094
        }, {
            d: 35.8,
            z: 07002
        }, {
            d: 39.6,
            z: 06460
        }, {
            d: 43.2,
            z: 06484
        }, {
            d: 15.0,
            z: 11581
        }, {
            d: 48.1,
            z: 07753
        }, {
            d: 37.9,
            z: 06614
        }, {
            d: 27.2,
            z: 10601
        }, {
            d: 0.0,
            z: 11735
        }]
    };
alert(p[11735][1].z);
```

Expected output should be 07047 but actual output is 3623

I don't know why is it happening. Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`07047` is interpreted as a base 8 number since it begins with a `0`.

`07047 (base 8) === 3623 (base 10)`

http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-8-to-base-10-conversion.html

If you want `07047` to be the number `7047` in base 10, then simply remove the `0` at the beginning.

Comment: @Pavan do you understand the issue now?

Comment: You can also use the parseInt function passing the base. For example `parseInt(p[11735][1].z,10)`

Comment: @Jack that will not work in this case, because by the time `parseInt()` is called it'll be too late.

Comment: @Pointy good point, I suppose he could have them stored as strings and then call parseInt, but if he has access to the data source then he might as well remove the leading 0.

Comment: you can pass `parseInt()` a number and it will convert the value to a string for you so you don't have to store them as strings if you don't want to. `parseInt(41, 16) == 65` works just as well as `parseInt('41', 16) == 65`

Comment: Thanks, @ZachSadler for the explanation. i have access to data source so i will make the change there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting - I just discovered that octal escape sequences (\ followed by one, two, or three octal digits) are deprecated in string and regular expression literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

Comment: @MaxWorg You can pass it a number, but the problem in this case is that the number in the *p* object will already have been converted because of the leading zero so it is as *pointy* mentioned too late.

Comment: +1 for @Jack and @Pointy for teaching me something new.  So it seems that using `parseInt` will work in all cases except for when dealing with numbering systems that allow leading zeros.